# WebGuy codeception

Tags: php, codeception

I'm new using codeception and i try to do a simple test: Log in and check links inside.

I'm using `$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);` in my acceptance test but i see people using `WebGuy($scenario)` and **i don't know the difference between WebGuy and AcceptanceTester.**

SigninCept.php code:

```
<?php 
//webLOG IN
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Log in my app mobile');
//$I->amOnUrl('192.168.X.X/app/mobile/');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->fillField('user','test');
$I->fillField('password','test1234');
$I->fillField('zone','01');
//$I->uncheckOption('input[type=checkbox]');
$I->seeCheckboxIsChecked('#rememberme');
$I->seeElement('input[name=submit]');
$I->click('input[type=submit]');

//succes
$I->wantTo('Check main page');
$I->amOnPage('/principal.php');
$I->seeLink('salir','salir.php');
[...]
?>
```

**Result(cmd):**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\codeception>php codecept.phar run acceptance --steps

Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.0.9
Powered by PHPUnit 4.4.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Acceptance Tests (1) -----------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
Trying to Log in App Mobile (SigninCept)

Scenario:
* I am on page "/"
* I fill field "user","test"
* I fill field "password","test1234"
* I fill field "zone","01"
* I see checkbox is checked "#rememberme"
* I see element "input[name=submit]"
* I click "input[type=submit]"
* I am on page "/principal.php"
* I see link "salir","salir.php"
[...]
PASSED
```

**When i use `$I = new WebGuy($scenario);` i get this:**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\codeception>php codecept.phar run acceptance --steps

Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.0.9
Powered by PHPUnit 4.4.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Acceptance Tests (1) -----------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
Trying to Log in App mobile(SigninCept)

Scenario:

Fatal error: Class 'WebGuy' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\codeception\tests\acceptance\SigninCept.php on line 3



FATAL ERROR. TESTS NOT FINISHED.
Class 'WebGuy' not found
```

in C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\codeception\tests\acceptance\SigninCept.php:3

```
I have **WebGuy.php in my acceptance dir.**
```

If i do **build** i get this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\codeception>php codecept.phar build acceptance --steps



[RuntimeException]
Too many arguments.



build [-c|--config[="..."]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Codeception 2.x use only AcceptanceTester.

> As it was said, Guys were renamed to Testers. Actor classes and
>   helpers are named by suite. For instance, acceptance test will start
>   with this line:

```
<?php
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
// and uses AcceptanceHelper
?>
```

See here : http://codeception.com/06-06-2014/codeception-2.0-final.html

Answer (score 1):

The name of the "guy" depends on what you have in codeception configuration of your suite (in your case the acceptance suite):

```
# acceptance.suite.yml
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver
    ...
```

When running `codecept build` the guy class will be created integrating all the methods of the modules you have defined, and it will then used by CodeCeption when running the tests. Any other classes will be ignored.

Also see the help for the build command (`codecept help build`) to see what options you can pass to it (i.e. normally you don't need any option).

Answer (score 0):

the `WebGuy` class is only a custom class that extends from the `AcceptanceTester` Class. You can implement your own and call it from the `acceptance.suite.yml`

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester ==> or  ==> WebGuy // here is the call of the class
modules:
   enabled: 
      - WebDriver:
         url: 'http://local.symmetryk.com/'
         browser: firefox
         window_size: maximize
         wait: 10
         capabilities:
             unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept'

        env:
        chrome:
         modules:
            config:
                WebDriver:
                    browser: 'chrome'

      - Db:
```

hope this will help you understand :)